# Apply physics to multiple objects using script

Tags: python, scripting, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to apply physics properties to multiple objects using following script:

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
     bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add(type='ACTIVE')
```

but physics is applied only to the last object. Do you have any suggestions? I know how to copy physics using 'Copy from Active' but i need script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup one object as template then the following code will set the template object as active object and select all objects. Finally `bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_settings_copy()` copies all attributes as the 'Copy from Active' button would do.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["template"]  
for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        obj.select = True


#bpy.ops.object.constraints_copy()
bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_settings_copy()
```

Answer (score 4):

This should also do the trick:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()

bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_settings_copy()
```

It adds rigid body to the active object and then copies the rigid body setting to all other selected objects

This will also make rigid body all the selected objects:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='ACTIVE')
```